# Displaying MIT license modifications

Tags: copyright, mit

### Background:

I created an unofficial OSGeo addon, [24dev-demo](https://github.com/pmcgover/24dev-demo) for a student's "Software Digital Portfolio" via github.com. A student may add or modify the software with their own code. Below is an example of a modified MIT license header they could use:

```
Original work Copyright (c) 2015 John David Doe

Modified "appName", Added "appName" Copyright 2016 Mary Carol Doe
```

### Question:

What is the proper/best way for a developer to "publish" their modifications/additions to the original MIT copyright license?

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean by "publish" their modifications/additions to the original MIT copyright license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the license file of a "template" project: https://github.com/gmalecha/coq-plugin-template/blob/master/LICENSE.

And the README contains this instruction:

> 7) Update the LICENSE file by completing the line for your copyright claim or add your own license statement if you don't want to use MIT.

MIT license doesn't require anything more (no need for instance to list the modifications that were made).

Comment: I read the MIT license text, '...and this permission notice shall be included in all copies...' to imply that the developer should include the permission notice of the original copy.  Is there any harm in listing it as I have?

Comment: No there is no harm in suggesting listing modifications as you propose. The most important thing, as you remarked, is that the permission that came with the software is kept.